# can't make a page root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am a noob in ruby on rails so excuse this question if it is a stupid one :

I've added in my routes.rb the command :

> `root :to => "pages#home"`

a have generated a pages-controller using

```
rails generate controller pages
```

in my pages_controller.rb i've defined a function named home :

```
def home
@text = "da"
end
```

in the views folder from my app in the newly generated pages folder i've created a file named home.html.erb . in it i've placed the following command :

```
<%= @text %>
```

The problem is that when i start the server my app isn't rooted in home and even when i run 
localhost:3000/pages/home it still doesn't work :

```
No route matches "/home"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a controller but no view, try these commands

```
$ rails new myapp
$ cd myapp
$ rails g controller pages index    <- this will create a controller **plus** an index view
$ rm public/index.html
```

now edit routes.rb and add `root :to => "pages#index`

```
$ rails s
```

open http://localhost:3000 and you'll see the new page.

I'm a noob too (I started coding in ruby 2 weeks ago)... I **strongly** suggest you to get a book, such as [Agile Web Development with Rails 4th ed](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails). I covered the book in a week and it gave me a LOT of insight about ruby and rails.

Comment: it wasn't working because i didn't delete the index file from public :)) now it works. Thanks for the book tip ! +1